# Java - как установить имя(загаловок) программы?

Tags: java

Я недавно что начал изучать джаву, и толком тут ничего не знаю.
Мне нужно как то поставить имя программы, то есть имя окна.

Comment: Если расскажешь, какой фреймворк используешь, тебе <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При создании `JFrame` есть вариант конструктора `JFrame(String title)`  где вы можете указать его имя